# How to properly create testable scenarios during development?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, tdd, chromecast

While working on implementing Google's `Cast SDK` into an iOS application, I ran into this issue and wasn't able to come up with a scalable, efficient solution, but figure someone way smarter than me must be able to give me a few ideas:

Google's Chromecast iOS SDK comes with a `GCKDeviceScanner` class which manages the discovery of available cast receivers (ie. Chromecast HDMI dongles). In order to develop against that, it's obviously best to be in a room with a Chromecast plugged into an powered-on TV.

However, that may not always be possible nor does relying on available network resources make code easily testable. To solve, I created `MockGCKDeviceScanner` (a subclass of `GCKDeviceScanner`) and overwrote applicable methods to return me *fake receiver devices* for development/testing. Now I am able to continue coding even though no physical receivers may be available.

But I found integration into my actual classes rather cumbersome. In the example above, I have a

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) GCKDeviceScanner *scanner
```

But then, upon actual initialization I'm doing this rather ugly workaround:

```
#ifdef kDevMode
_scanner = [[MockGCKDeviceScanner alloc] init];
#else
_scanner = [[GCKDeviceScanner alloc] init];
#endif
```

That just doesn't look nice... and makes my code really cumbersome to read. What's the *right* way of doing such a thing?

Answer (score 0):

How are you running your tests? are you using any frameworks?

One option is to define two different schemes, one for each option. One of them could define in the scheme a system variable that will be used in runtime to decide which class to load for the tests

Comment: I'm using XCTest for testing.. But more so, I'm wondering how to do it during development (here: if no physical devices are around).

Answer (score 0):

You could "[inject](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection)" the scanner through the constructor, deferring the selection of the concrete class to the caller.

Depending on how deep in the object graph this is, you may need some sort of [locator](http://martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html#UsingAServiceLocator) object as well, at the cost of introducing a global reference.